# VSCode React-Native not underlining when need to import

Tags: reactjs, react-native, visual-studio-code

For example, writing `<Button />` doesn't automatically red underline telling me to import from 'react-native'.

VSCode is doing this for other projects I have, but not this one in React-Native. How do I activate this?

Comment: Do you find any solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that at this time, there are unfortunately no good plug-ins/libraries that support this for VSCode.